# ParserError shown in my code

Tags: solidity

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

import './IERC20.sol';

Contract Lifecoin is IERC20 {

    uint public constant _totalSupply = 3000000000;

    string public constant symbol = "LFC";
    string public constant name = "Lifecoin";
    uint8 public constant decimal = 8;

    mapping(address => uint256) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) allowed;

    function Lifecoin() {
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance)
        return balances[_owner];     
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {       
        require(
            balances[msg.sender] => _value
            && _value > 0 
            );
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;       
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success){
        require(
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] => _value
            && balances[_from] => _value
            && _value > 0 
        );
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer[_from, _to, _value];
        returns true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
         return allowed[_owner][_spender];
     }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value)

}
```

Comment: what is your question?, what is the error?

Comment: Please edit your post and paste in your parse error.

Answer (score 1):

The points where you get the errors are quite clear and easy to fix.

- use `contract` instead of `Contract` in line 5
- Line 26 is missing `{`
- Line 34 & 46 & 47 use `>=` instead of `=>`
- Line 53 should be `Transfer(_from, _to, _value);`
- Line 54 `return` instead of `returns`
- Line 67 & 68 missing `;` at the end
- Missing closing `}` at the end